# Elasticsearch - Kibana - Group By and Count

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, kibana, querydsl

i basically have this dataset:

userid: 123456
content: Lorem ispum

userid: 123456
content: Lorem ispum

userid: 123456
content: Lorem ispum

userid: 1234567
content: Lorem ispum

userid: 1234567
content: Lorem ispum

userid: 12345678
content: Lorem ispum

What i want to see:

How many users have one entry?, two entries?, three entries? etc.

I already know how i can see "How many entries" per user but i want the inverse...

Anybody could help me with this issue?
Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: I'm looking for something similar, see here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020792/double-aggregate-data-nested-aggregation-and-plot-in-a-bar-chart-in-kibana)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pie chart visualisation, split the chart by user and then add a sub-bucket and then split it by the entry (assuming the entry is an aggregatable field).